# What kind of join should I use or should I make models for that?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have 3 tables - `carts`, `cart_products` and `products`.

Their structure look like this:

carts:

```
id, employee_id, name, paid
```

cart_products:

```
id, cart_id, product_id, amount
```

products:

```
id, name, price
```

Now in my code I grab all the unpaid carts:

```
$carts = Cart::where('paid', false)->select('id')->get();
```

and iterate over them:

```
foreach ($carts as $key) {
    $cart_products = DB::table('cart_products')
    ->where('cart_id', $key->id)
    ->get();

    $returnedCarts[] = [
        'id' => $key->id,
        'name' => $key->name,
        'products'=> $cart_products      
    ];
}

return response()->json($returnedCarts);
```

Now my question is how can I change my JSON containing products from this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": null,
    "products": [ //this is the cart_products table
        {
            "id": 1,
            "cart_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "amount": 2,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }
    ]
},
```

Into this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": null,
    "products": [ //this is data from the products table
        {
            "product_id": 1,
            "amount": 2, //but this is from the cart_products table
            "name": "This product name",
            "price" "$9,49"
        }
    ]
},
```

Without additional queries in the foreach loop. What kind of join should I use? Should I change my code or maybe should I use models instead of the DB facade?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Laravel Eloquent, [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

First of all, define the relationship in your models:

```
# Cart.php

use App\Product;

// ...

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('amount');
} //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^relationship    ^^^^^^^^^aditional intermediate columns
```

Then, in your controller you can do:

```
# CartsController.php

use App\cart;

// ...

public function yourFunction()
{
    $carts = Cart
         ::with('products') // <-- Eager loading the relationship 'products'
         ->where('paid', false) // <-- constraining the query
         ->get();  // <-- executing the query.

    return $carts;
}
```

This will give you something similar to this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cart name",
    "products": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "This product name",
            "price" "$9,49",
            "pivot": {   // <-- notice this
                 "amount": 2
             },
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use models because you can eager-load the products and you save up some queries (read more later on) and, by using models, you can take advantage of using Eloquent API Resources that gives you better control on your output (which fields, in which order, where to get them, etc).

#### N+1 Query Problem

You are now suffering from the **N+1 query problem** because you get all the *N unpaid carts (1 query)*, and *for each* of them you get their products (*N query*, one for each cart).

#### Implementing Model relationship

In the Cart model you can set up a relationship to the product like so:

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('amount');
}
```

You can also add a query scope, to simply keep the where condition that tells you a cart is unpaid in the model and not in the controller (you will find out later how to use it):

```php
public function scopeUnpaid($query)
{
    return $query->where('paid', false);
}
```

#### API Resources

To implement Eloquent API Resource you have to:

1. Create the API Resource classes for Cart and Product with artisan:

```
php artisan make:resource Cart
```

```
php artisan make:resource Product
```

> These command will create two files `app/Http/Resources/Cart.php` and `app/Http/Resources/Product.php`.

2. Edit the Cart resource to display the fields you want in your output, otherwise all the cart fields will be returned:

```php
// Do not forget the use statement at the top
use App\Http\Resources\Product as ProductResource;

// Then replace the toArray method
public function toArray($request)
{
    // $this refers to the current Cart instance
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        // This line tells to render each product of this cart with the Product API Resource,
        // in this way you can also control how each product model will be displayed
        // in the json response
        'products' => ProductResource::collection($this->products)
    ];
}
```

3. Edit the Product resource to display the output the way you want:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    // $this refers to the current Product instance
    // As you requested, here you can set the field and it's value.
    return [
        'product_id' => $this->id,
        // this field is taken from the cart_product table, that is loaded
        // as you specified to load the amount attribute with the ->withPivot('amount')
        // instruction in your products() relation
        'amount' => $this->pivot->amount,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'price' => $this->price
    ];
}
```

In controller you can now eager-load all the products for the unpaid carts and use the API resources to edit what will be sent as a response to only show the attributes you need.

```
// Do not forget to import the Cart model and the Cart Resource at the top
use App\Cart;
use App\Http\Resources\Cart as CartResource;

public function your_method()
{
    // You can use the unpaid() query scope you added earlier
    // as a simple shorthand to ->where('paid', false') function
    // on the query builder.
    // ->with('products') will eager-load the products relationship
    // and therefore retrive the products associated to the carts you
    // are gonna retrive with just one additional query, not one for each cart.
    $carts = Cart::unpaid()->with('products')->get();

    return CartResource::collection($carts);
}
```

You can look at the documentations about API Resources [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources) and about eager-loading [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: I like your answer, +1 for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you for all the details, I learned something new. +1 for you, however I marked the simplified post as the answer, but IMHO this should be kept up.